# Can I attack with two weapons in a single attack action with Extra Attack (not including any bonus action)?

Tags: dnd-5e, two-weapon-fighting

Say my character is a 5th level monk with the Extra Attack feature and I am holding a dagger in one hand and a short sword in the other: Can I use the Attack action to swing the Short Sword with my first attack, throw the dagger with the second, and then use Martial Arts to make an Unarmed Attack with my bonus action?

Comment: Hi Josh, welcome to the site! Good first question. Check out our [tour] for  an overview on how the various parts of our site work, and when you reach 20 rep, you'll be able to join our [chat].